# How did Mad-Eye Moody recognize Neville, Ron, and others?

Tags: harry-potter

In their first Defense Against the Dark Arts class with Mad-Eye Moody,

> ...who was really Barty Crouch in disguise...

Mad-Eye calls out by name Neville, Ron, Lavender Brown, Seamus Finnegan, and I think Hermione. Though how does he know who they are?

> Especially considering that Barty Crouch was in Azkaban for the last few years and has probably never met most of them.

Comment: Seating plan? Hogwarts yearbook?

Comment: As the only person in the world ever with an "I survived Avada Kedavra" scar, I'd imagine Harry is fairly easy to identify...

Comment: To be honest, I would consider it poor planning and preparation if an INFILTRATOR in HOGWARDS fails to be adequately sourced.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### He's already done a roll call

He can connect names to faces because he took attendance at the start of the lesson:

> Moody took out a register, shook his long mane of grizzled gray hair out of his twisted and scarred face, and began to call out names, his normal eye moving steadily down the list while his magical eye swiveled around, fixing upon each student as he or she answered.
>
> <sup>*Goblet of Fire* Chapter 14: "The Unforgivable Curses"</sup>

After that, it would be trivial for him to connect Ron and Neville to their parents, who he would most assuredly know.

Skimming over that part of the chapter, there's no special indication that he recognized Hermione; the extent of their interactions in that first lesson are:

- > "So... do any of you know which curses are most heavily punished by wizarding law?"
  >
  > Several hands rose tentatively into the air, including Ron's and Hermione's. Moody pointed at Ron
  >
  > <sup>*Goblet of Fire* Chapter 14: "The Unforgivable Curses"</sup>
- > "Anyone else know one? Another illegal curse?"
  >
  > Hermione's hand flew into the air again and so, to Harry's slight surprise, did Neville's.
  >
  > <sup>*Goblet of Fire* Chapter 14: "The Unforgivable Curses"</sup>
- > Moody did not remove his wand, and the spider started to shudder and jerk more violently —
  >
  > "Stop it!" Hermione said shrilly.
  >
  > Harry looked around at her. She was looking, not at the spider,
  >   but at Neville
  >
  > <sup>*Goblet of Fire* Chapter 14: "The Unforgivable Curses"</sup>
- > Hermione's hand shook slightly as, for the third time, she raised it into the air.
  >
  > "Yes?" said Moody, looking at her.
  >
  > "*Avada Kedavra*," Hermione whispered.
  >
  > <sup>*Goblet of Fire* Chapter 14: "The Unforgivable Curses"</sup>

He does recognize Lavender, which may be what you're thinking of, but that's easily explained by the previously-mentioned roll call:

> You need to be prepared. You need to be alert and watchful. You need to put
>   that away, Miss Brown, when I'm talking."
>
> Lavender jumped and blushed. She had been showing Parvati her completed horoscope under the desk.
>
> <sup>*Goblet of Fire* Chapter 14: "The Unforgivable Curses"</sup>

### In the film

This is harder to answer in the context of the films, which generally don't have time to spend on this sort of minutia. No explicit answer is given, but we can imagine some possibilities:

- He called the roll off-screen. Since the scene picks up with class already in session, this is plausible
- When I went to school, the teachers had sheets with the names and pictures of every student in their classes. I don't know if this is common in England, or at Hogwarts, but would be a plausible explanation
- We know that Moody has been talking with other teachers:

  > **Moody:** Professor Sprout tells me you [Neville, obviously] have an aptitude for herbology.
  >
  > <sup>*Goblet of Fire* (2005)</sup>

  It seems likely that he could have learned about other students through these sorts of off-screen conversations

Comment: Ah. I see now I've confused the books and the movies. In the movie there was no "roll call" scene yet he called out Seamus, Ron, Neville, and Hermione.

Comment: @LCIII Added a bit about the film. I haven't seen it in years, though, so I make no guarantees about accuracy

Comment: why would Mad-eye know who Ron's parents are?

Comment: Order of the Phoenix, plus Moody and Arthur both work at the Ministry.

Comment: @Traceur Mad-eye knows them from the original Order of the Phoenix, and Crouch Jr. has likely met Arthur; the incident earlier in the book where Arthur went to bail out Moody (also referenced in this same chapter) is heavily implied, if not outright stated, to be Crouch taking Moody's place

Comment: I think you're wrong about the Order, as the Weasleys weren't part of the original one if I recall.  However you make a good point about the incident at Moody's house and I just remembered the Quidditch cup! Jr was there in an invisibilty cloak

Comment: @Traceur Ah, you're right; I did misremember the Order. Regardless, it's stated outright earlier in *Goblet of Fire* that Moody and Arthur are at least cordial acquaintances, and at the very least he should have recognized him from that same incident